# AngularJS RouteProvider. To know what user hits when it goes to "otherwise"

Tags: angularjs, routes

Let's say I have the routes:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.

    when('/', {templateUrl:     'partials/myView.html'}).

    otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' } );

}]);
```

I would like to know what `url` is (which user hits) when it goes to '`otherwise`'. To put this url to the console log for example.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `redirectTo` parameter can be a function ([source](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)), so you can do this

```
redirectTo: function(params, currentPath) {
  console.log(currentPath);
  return '/';
}
```